# Adobe Air ProductStore Ane restoreTransactions() doens't work in Sandbox

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, in-app-purchase, in-app

I'm using ProductStore by Adobe to implement In-App Purchase on iOS.

I can purchase a product, it works fine. (I listen to  PURCHASE_TRANSACTION_CANCEL, PURCHASE_TRANSACTION_FAIL and PURCHASE_TRANSACTION_SUCCESS, _productStore.makePurchaseTransaction(PRODUCT_ID), call _productStore.makePurchaseTransaction(PRODUCT_ID), and than event PURCHASE_TRANSACTION_SUCCESS is fired)

Also I have to know if the product was purchased already. So I listen to RESTORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETE, RESTORE_TRANSACTION_FAIL and RESTORE_TRANSACTION_SUCCESS events and call restoreTransactions(). When all the previous transactions are done firing their PURCHASE_SUCCEEDED events, RESTORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETE should be dispatched. But I receive the RESTORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETE and no RESTORE_TRANSACTION_SUCCESS.

So, questions:

1. When I'm testing my app, Sandbox is proceeding all my requests. May the problem be related to Sandbox?
2. In _productStore.pendingTransactions I do have one transaction with receipt and with my PRODUCT_ID. What does it mean?

Thank you in advance,
Olga

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself "But I receive the RESTORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETE and no RESTORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETE." could you clarify?

Comment: Oops, it was mistake. I should write "But I receive the RESTORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETE and no RESTORE_TRANSACTION_SUCCESS

Comment: I've changed the ANE to MilkMan's In-App Purchase ANe and now my app works fine